# Do non-enzyme catalysed reaction pathways exist?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, cell-biology, enzymes, pathway

Can their be a kind of chemical reaction pathway in a cell, that is catalyzed or regulated but NOT necessarily by enzymes? I could not find anything on Google.

I have almost no background in biology, and am only studying certain topics from a mathematical perspective.

Answer (score 1):

If by enzyme you mean "protein" *aka* polypeptide, than there are such things as [catalitic RNAs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ribozyme). Those are molecules of RNA that facilitate chemical reactions but don't change themselves (definition of catalyst). I think that, based on the discovery of such RNAs, it is now believed that life might have started from or with the help of catalytic RNAs (please forgive the speculative tone, see [self-replicating RNAs](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=self-replicating%20rna&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart&sa=X&ei=ILk3VbDMEMzaoAS4joHYBQ&ved=0CBwQgQMwAA)).

You might find this article interesting: [The Road to Non-Enzymatic Molecular Networks](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18613152), which describes non-enzymatic networks. The problem with searching this topic is that [most current publications](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=non-enzymatic%20catalysis&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C5&as_sdtp=), seem to me, to concentrate on way to transfer enzymatic reactions into inorganic catalysis systems--because those systems can be more clean and easy to expand--than purifying enzymes for biotech.

Comment: This should rather be a comment than a full answer in my opinion. You make good points, but i think this needs to be elaborated.

Comment: in what way? also, RNAs are only example of pure non-protein catalysts I can think of. Others involve coenzymes, e.g. vitamins while they are part of proteins. There is not much surface metal catalysis in cellular biology (Pt)

Comment: Well, in my mind I was thinking of enzymes which help in metabolism, regulate intracellular reactions and such..

Comment: @aandreev - In a way that you describe what catalitc RNAs or ribozymes are, how do they work, what reactions do they play roles in. Also some peer-reviewed article on the topic would be nice. I too use wikipedia as source for explaining basic things in my answers but for the main topic I think peer reviewed literature is more suitable.

Comment: @jablesauce Well, that is not very common, after all cellular biology is protein-centered. I wish someone with more insight will answer.

Comment: The article you linked is is non-free and might not provide much help as I think it is inaccessible to most users. Also posting google scholar search results does not show too much effort.

Comment: @poka.nandor I try to avoid answering in comments, even if there might no be much to say on topic. But I think that _ribozymes_ are too googleable to expand on definitions/functions. In it I follow this meta@bio discussion: http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/questions/552/comments-with-answers

Comment: That is fine, but then take time and put effort in it to be nice elaborate answer. It's better for everyone.

Comment: -1 for not putting real effort in answering the question.